# Recording function and sensitivity calls in openmdao during an optimization

Tags: openmdao

I've been trying to figure out a good way to to record basic function calls and function calls to the sensitivity functions of my models in openmdao. I have not found an easy way to do this, but I think I must be missing something. What is the best way to record function calls and sensitivity function calls during an optimization? I need this information from regular runs, not just during debugging.

Answer (score 2):

The [OpenMDAO documentation](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/latest/index.html) has extensive info on this topic:
http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/latest/features/recording/index.html

Here is how to save your data:
http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/latest/features/recording/saving_data.html

And how to read it:
http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/latest/features/recording/reading_data.html